# Compare Time returned in string format by converting it to 24 hour format in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, datetime, time

I am making an ajax call and getting a JSON response. In the response I am getting time in following format:

```
12:00 pm //typeof of this is String.
```

I need to compare this time with the other times returned and find the earliest time.

What would be the best way of doing this?
I was thinking of converting it to 24 Hour format in int and then directly compare, but how can we convert this to 24 hour format in the best way?

Comment: cut off `am/pm` part, split remaining string into `hours/minutes`, if PM add 12 to `hours`, do `hours*60+minutes`, compare (don't forget 24=00)... that's it

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
   public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
       SimpleDateFormat displayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
       SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
       Date date = parseFormat.parse("12:00 PM");
       System.out.println(parseFormat.format(date) + " = " + displayFormat.format(date));
   }
}
```

That is what it prints:

```
12:00 PM = 00:00
```

Comment: You sure this is **JavaScript**?

Comment: Of course not. He didn't say anything about JavaScript. But even with i wrote he can write this in a class or even in a servlet and then to send in the JavaScript file. But if he wanted to do this in JavaScript it has surely easier ways.

Comment: Look at tags, below question ;) Also, mentioned JSON - **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation.

Comment: You are right. My fault

Comment: You need to delete this since it doesn't answer the question.